# While loop and mysql_fetch_array - Codeigniter equivalency

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to convert some ancient code to normal PHP standards (I've read about the issues with mysql functions...), I'm using Codeigniter as my framework, this is the original code:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT id,name from messages LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

$msg = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['message']);
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['msg_id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}

$msg = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
```

This is my attempt:

```
$this->load->model("main_model");
$result=$this->main_model->user_list($start, $per_page);

$msg = "";

foreach ($result->result() as $row){
     $htmlmsg = htmlentities($row->name);
     $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row->id . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}

$msg = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
```

My model:

```
function user_list($start, $per_page) {
    $query = $this->db->get('users', $start, $per_page); 
    return $query;
}
```

This is not working correctly though, I believe it has something to do with the while and how mysql_fetch_array works, I've tried a few solutions with a while loop, but don't seem to be getting there.

A bit more info: This is for an ajax pagination feature, my attempt above loads up results, but the foreach loop is now loading previous results in next pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function user_list($start, $per_page) {
   $query = $this->db->get('users', $per_page, $start);
   // flip $start/$per_page from your code
   return $query;
}
```

Comment: Gahhh, you're so right, damn you brain for forgetting Codeigniter syntax... will 'right' you up as soon as possible.